# How does one change a recursive function to an explicit function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recursion

Given that you have an initial constant $$f(0) = k$$
and a function f(n) which is given in terms of f(n-1), how would one eliminate the term f(n-1) and replace it with n, without compromising the function's output?

What are the general steps to achieve this for any given function? what functions can you not 'explicify' from a recursive function?

Comment: It really depends on how $f(n)$ & $f(n-1)$ are related ... sometimes it is easy to write down a general formula & sometimes it just becomes too difficult. Generating functions can often be helpful in solving such problems.

Comment: If the relationship is linear, such as for the Fibonacci numbers, you can do it by writing down the matrix that transforms $(f_{n-1}, f_{n-2})$ into $(f_n, f_{n-1})$, finding eigenvalues, and exponentiating.  That's a pretty versatile technique.

Comment: I found this link to be helpful for a good summary of the various techniques: http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Recurrence-Relations

Comment: Every recursive definition can be written non-recursively using a fixed point combinator, but that is mostly a grammatical trick.  Are you sure you'd be satisfied with just writing the function nonrecursively?  Most attempts at eliminating recursion are actually attempts at improving computational runtime.

Comment: @danielv that sounds useful.